# Find minimum value of 2 arguements

Tags: java, arrays, command-line, if-statement

I cannot find the syntax error here. Can anyone please help me to find this ?

Question is this - (2)  Write a program to get 2 values as command line arguments and find the Minimum of those 2 using if-else.

class MinNumber{

```
{
public static void main(String [] myArray){

    int length = myArray.length;

    if((myArray[0][0]) < (myArray[0][1])){
        System.out.println("Minimum number is : " + myArray[0][0]);
        }
    else{
        System.out.println("Minimum number is : " + myArray[0][1]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not compare `String` value with `<` since it is not primitive
Also Array is single array not double array.

Below is not safe code but simplest :

```
    if (Integer.parseInt(myArray[0]) < Integer.parseInt(myArray[1])) {
        System.out.println("Minimum number is : " + myArray[0]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Minimum number is : " + myArray[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks friend. This is working. Thanks a lot. I will accept the answer after 5 mins. God bless u !

Answer (score 0):

`myArray[0][0]` thats how you access elements of two dimensional array. `myArray[0]` is enough for one dimensional array.

So, you should parse the numbers out of `myArray[0]` and `myArray[1]` and compares them instead.

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem. 
in your main , notice the one dimension array?

```
public static void main(String [] myArray)
```

In your body, you are accessing it as 2D array.

```
if((myArray[0][0]) < (myArray[0][1])){
    System.out.println("Minimum number is : " + myArray[0][0]);
    }
```

By default ,The main method accepts a single argument: an array of elements of type String.
I am assuming that you actually meant to access the string from myArray ( as single dimension array) and proceed accordingly.

Also refer this if needed: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The argument taken by command line is of string type you firstly need to convert them in integer or float to make a number comparision.